# Microsoft Band Connectivity Issue

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I am using a Microsoft Band 2 and running through some of the sample tutorials however am having problems with the Band not being a connected device despite the OS saying it is connected.

I'm using Windows 10, VS 2015 and have checked that the Band firmware is up to date.  I have also disconnected the device and repaired it.  This was slightly problematic as the OS threw a Driver Problem error message.  The strange thing is it has worked although I have repaired the Band with my phone and this issue has happened after that.

You can see from the screen shot that the Device is paired but in stepping through the code it claims there are no paired Bands.

Any input would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Band will connect only to the most-recently-paired device (despite it possibly being paired to multiple devices).  If you re-paired the Band to your phone, it would be expected *not* to connect to your desktop until you've re-paired the Band to your desktop.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your response.  Unfortunately I have repaired the band to the laptop which is when I got the Driver Error mentioned but after having restarting the machine and successfully repairing the device I still got the behavior in the screenshot.